# Ajax call which return a file or a partial html on case of error - how to handle that?

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, download

Let suppose we have a dialog with some settings, then on dialog button "OK" the settings are sent to a controller function via AJAX call. This call either result a downloadable file, or an error described in a (partial) html source code. In latter case this error message must be inserted into the dialog.

```
$.ajax( { 
   url: url, 
   data: dialogFormData, 
   success: function(data) { ???? }
});
```

How to handle this situation? How to handle the ajax response to process the result? Any idea?

Comment: What is your JQuery version?

Comment: It was only an example. Is it important? Is there any version-specific idea of yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to check the response type and act accordingly.
You can try something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url, 
  data: dialogFormData, 
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('multipart/form-data') > -1) {
      // do something with file
    }
    if (ct.indexOf('text/html') > -1) {
      // do something with html
    } 
  }
});
```

I didn't test this code, you may need to play around with the types to get the correct ones.

Comment: I like it! Thanks the idea!

Comment: By the way - if ct holds a file - how to save from the success func?

Comment: You want to prompt the user to save the file? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/4551467#4551467).

Comment: Thx. I will. Seems very interesting!